# Cannot access elements by id/name inside my HelloWorld.js from my HelloWorld.html file

Tags: javascript, html, adobe-animate

I am using Adobe Animate to export a website and it gives me this folder:

[image]

My main file is this HelloWorld.html. The other HelloWorld.js gets generated by Animate and here is where all of my html objects get autogenerated (labels, buttons, etc).

Once I run it I get this

[image]

All I know is every time I make a design change to my website this HelloWorld.js file gets overwritten. Which is fine, I suppose. But, I do need access to these elements. All I am given to work with is the .html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    NOTES:
    1. All tokens are represented by '$' sign in the template.
    2. You can write your code only wherever mentioned.
    3. All occurrences of existing tokens will be replaced by their appropriate values.
    4. Blank lines will be removed automatically.
    5. Remove unnecessary comments before creating your template.
-->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="authoring-tool" content="Adobe_Animate_CC">
<title>HelloWorld</title>
<!-- write your code here -->
<style>
  #animation_container {
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    left:0;right:0;
    top:0;bottom:0;
  }
</style>
<script src="libs/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="HelloWorld.js"></script>
 
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot, anim_container, dom_overlay_container, fnStartAnimation;
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    anim_container = document.getElementById("animation_container");
    dom_overlay_container = document.getElementById("dom_overlay_container");
    var comp=AdobeAn.getComposition("8F022118589B1141A961E277C0AE693B");
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.addEventListener("fileload", function(evt){handleFileLoad(evt,comp)});
    loader.addEventListener("complete", function(evt){handleComplete(evt,comp)});
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}
function handleFileLoad(evt, comp) {
    var images=comp.getImages();    
    if (evt && (evt.item.type == "image")) { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }    
}
function handleComplete(evt,comp) {
    //This function is always called, irrespective of the content. You can use the variable "stage" after it is created in token create_stage.
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    var ss=comp.getSpriteSheet();
    var queue = evt.target;
    var ssMetadata = lib.ssMetadata;
    for(i=0; i<ssMetadata.length; i++) {
        ss[ssMetadata[i].name] = new createjs.SpriteSheet( {"images": [queue.getResult(ssMetadata[i].name)], "frames": ssMetadata[i].frames} )
    }
    exportRoot = new lib.HelloWorld();
    stage = new lib.Stage(canvas);  
    //Registers the "tick" event listener.
    fnStartAnimation = function() {
        stage.addChild(exportRoot);
        createjs.Ticker.framerate = lib.properties.fps;
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
    }       
    //Code to support hidpi screens and responsive scaling.
    AdobeAn.makeResponsive(false,'both',false,1,[canvas,anim_container,dom_overlay_container]); 
    AdobeAn.compositionLoaded(lib.properties.id);
    fnStartAnimation();
 
}
</script>
<!-- write your code here -->'

<script>
  
});
</script>

</head>
<body onload="init();" style="margin:0px;">
    <div id="animation_container" style="background-color:rgba(0, 204, 153, 1.00); width:800px; height:600px">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" style="position: absolute; display: block; background-color:rgba(0, 204, 153, 1.00);"></canvas>
        <div id="dom_overlay_container" style="pointer-events:none; overflow:hidden; width:800px; height:600px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside the HelloWorld.js this is the function where my elements get created:

```
// stage content:
(lib.HelloWorld = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
    var props = new Object();
    props.mode = mode;
    props.startPosition = startPosition;
    props.labels = {};
    props.loop = loop;
    props.reversed = reversed;
    cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

    this.actionFrames = [0];
    this.isSingleFrame = false;
    // timeline functions:
    this.frame_0 = function() {
        if(this.isSingleFrame) {
            return;
        }
        if(this.totalFrames == 1) {
            this.isSingleFrame = true;
        }
        /* Button Click Event
        Clicking on the specified button executes this function in which you can add your own custom code.
        
        Instructions:
        1. Add your custom code on a new line after the line that says "// Start your custom code" below.
        */
        
        if(!this.SendInfoButton_click_cbk) {
            function SendInfoButton_click(evt) {
                // Start your custom code
                console.log("Button clicked");
                alert('Click')
                // End your custom code
            }
            $("#dom_overlay_container").on("click", "#SendInfoButton", SendInfoButton_click.bind(this));
            this.SendInfoButton_click_cbk = true;
        }
    }

    // actions tween:
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).call(this.frame_0).wait(1));

    // Animation
    this.instance = new lib.circleAnimation();
    this.instance.setTransform(36.25,34.05,0.1804,0.1804);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

    // Buttons
    this.GetInfoButton = new lib.an_Button({'id': 'GetInfoButton', 'label':'Get Info', 'disabled':false, 'visible':true, 'class':'ui-button'});

    this.GetInfoButton.name = "GetInfoButton";
    this.GetInfoButton.setTransform(102.05,156.85,1,1,0,0,0,50,11);

    this.SendInfoButton = new lib.an_Button({'id': 'SendInfoButton', 'label':'Send Info', 'disabled':false, 'visible':true, 'class':'ui-button'});

    this.SendInfoButton.name = "SendInfoButton";
    this.SendInfoButton.setTransform(102.05,106.05,1,1,0,0,0,50,11);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.SendInfoButton},{t:this.GetInfoButton}]}).wait(1));

    // Lights_mc
    this.Light_1 = new lib.Light_mc();
    this.Light_1.name = "Light_1";
    this.Light_1.setTransform(177.25,377.3,1,1,0,0,0,41.2,12.5);

    this.Light_1_1 = new lib.Light_mc();
    this.Light_1_1.name = "Light_1_1";
    this.Light_1_1.setTransform(187.25,343.65,1,1,0,0,0,51.2,12.5);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.Light_1_1},{t:this.Light_1}]}).wait(1));

    // Textfields
    this.instance_1 = new lib.CachedBmp_5();
    this.instance_1.setTransform(351.25,329.8,0.5,0.5);

    this.textfield_1 = new cjs.Text("Text 1", "20px 'Arial'", "#FFFFFF");
    this.textfield_1.name = "textfield_1";
    this.textfield_1.lineHeight = 24;
    this.textfield_1.lineWidth = 321;
    this.textfield_1.parent = this;
    this.textfield_1.setTransform(416.5,260.85);

    this.textfield_2 = new cjs.Text("Text 2", "20px 'Arial'", "#FFFFFF");
    this.textfield_2.name = "textfield_2";
    this.textfield_2.lineHeight = 24;
    this.textfield_2.lineWidth = 321;
    this.textfield_2.parent = this;
    this.textfield_2.setTransform(416.5,215.85);

    this.textfield_3 = new cjs.Text("Text 3", "20px 'Arial'", "#FFFFFF");
    this.textfield_3.name = "textfield_4";
    this.textfield_3.lineHeight = 24;
    this.textfield_3.lineWidth = 321;
    this.textfield_3.parent = this;
    this.textfield_3.setTransform(54.05,260.85);

    this.instance_4 = new lib.CachedBmp_1();
    this.instance_4.setTransform(233,28.6,0.5,0.5);

    this.instance_5 = new lib.CachedBmp_2();
    this.instance_5.setTransform(6.5,6.5,0.5,0.5);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.instance_5},{t:this.instance_4},{t:this.sendInfo_1_text},{t:this.sendInfo_2_text},{t:this.textfield_3},{t:this.textfield_4},{t:this.textfield_5},{t:this.textfield_6},{t:this.instance_3},{t:this.instance_2},{t:this.light_1_value},{t:this.light_2_value},{t:this.instance_1}]}).wait(1));

    // outlines
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f().s("#FFFFFF").ss(1,1,1).p("Eg4egH4MBw9AAAIAAPxMhw9AAAg");
    this.shape.setTransform(401.475,134.55);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

    // Background
    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.f("#0066CC").s().p("Eg+fAu4MAAAhdvMB8/AAAMAAABdvg");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(400,300);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape_1).wait(1));

    this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = p = new lib.AnMovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(400,300,400,300);
// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    id: '8F022118589B1141A961E277C0AE693B',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    fps: 24,
    color: "#000000",
    opacity: 1.00,
    manifest: [
        {src:"images/HelloWorld_atlas_1.png", id:"HelloWorld_atlas_1"},
        {src:"components/lib/jquery-3.4.1.min.js", id:"lib/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"},
        {src:"components/sdk/anwidget.js", id:"sdk/anwidget.js"},
        {src:"components/ui/src/button.js", id:"an.Button"}
    ],
    preloads: []
};
```

I have tried to access the "Text 1" text field by writing the following inside the `<script>` tags :

```
<script>
  const demoId = document.getElementById('#textfield_1');
  console.log(demoId);
</script>
```

but all I get is null when I check the console window which brings the initial question around: Given my current set up, how can I access a text field and change its value?

Comment: I have absolute no idea from adobe animate. but from what i see, i dont think it works like you think it works. the html page contains a canvas and a div-overlay that takes the user catches the user input like mouse clicks. the buttons and labels you mention are drawn to the canvas, they are not html elements and not part of the dom so i dont think you can access them with javascript and getelementbyid. have you tried the dom inspector of your browser to verify that button/label/textfield are actual html elements?

Comment: @Michael I have not tried dom inspector. I'll give it a go and check. Thank you

Comment: If you are using chrome, firefox or edge on windows you can press `ctrl + shift + c` to get into element selector mode (dont know if its really called like that). but in that mode, you can move the mouse on the page and the html elements you hover will be highlighted in the lower pane. test in on a normal website to see how it works and then have a look at your adobe animate project

Comment: `getElementById` already knows you're passing an `id` (hence the name), so remove the `#`.

Comment: *I have tried to access the "Text 1" text field by writing the following inside the <script> tags* Did you put the script tag at the end of the body? Otherwise it won't be able to find the elements. HTML is parsed top down, and JS can only access parsed elements.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't give the '#' in the getElementById function:

```
const demoId = document.getElementById('textfield_1');
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I still tried it without the '#' character and its still returning null. I saw Michael's comment and I'll do some research on that "dom inspector" and see if that's what I need. Thank you.